# promise catch: how to know if the error comes from promise rejection or from the then statement

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Imagine a function that returns a promise (for example fetch from fetch API):

```
fetch(...)
.then((response) => {...})
.catch((error) => {...});
```

How can I know if the error inside the `catch` statement has been originated due to a promise rejection instead from the code inside the `then` statement?

Something like the following will work:

```
let success = false;
fetch(...)
.then((response) => {success = true; ...})
.catch((error) => {if(success) ...});
```

But I want to know if there is a better or more native way to do it. I have also tried to do something like:

```
fetch(...)
.catch((promiseError) => {...});
.then((response) => {...})
.catch((thenError) => {...});
```

But I think it doesn't work because `response` isn't forwarded to the `then`statement (or at least that's what TS says).

Which would be the better way?

Comment: You can look at `error.message` to determine what caused it. Or you can use try catch blocks and await the promises, that way you can catch the errors separately. The best approach depends on what your actual goal is.

Comment: One way to handle this is to define a custom error class and _throw_ the instance of that custom error class from the callback function of the `then` method. Inside the callback function of the `catch` method, you can check if the error parameter is an instance of your custom error class or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`then` accepts two parameters¹: A function to call on fulfillment, and another to call on rejection. So you can handle the initial rejection earlier:

```
fetch(/*...*/)
.then(
    // Fulfillment handler
    (response) => {
        /*...*/
    },
    // Rejection handler for `fetch` promise
    (error) => {
        /*...*/
    }
)
.catch((error) => {
    // This rejection handler only sees errors not handled above
});
```

The first rejection handler (in the `then` call) is only called for rejections of the promise from `fetch`, not rejections caused by errors in the fulfillment handler.

The second rejection handler (in the `catch` call) is called for rejections caused by errors (or rejected promises) from the handlers that come before it (either fulfillment or rejection); it doesn't get called if the original promise is rejected (but it may well get called if the first rejection handler throws an error or returns a promise that is/will be rejected).

So in those cases where you care, you can handle it closer to the source.

**Note** that all rejection handlers that don't either throw an error or return a promise that is/will be rejected convert rejection (of the original promise) into fulfillment (of the one from `then`/`catch`). That can matter for downstream `then` handlers.

---

A key thing to understanding this is to remember that `then` (and its wrappers `catch` and `finally`) **return a new promise**. That's why:

```
aPromise.then(onFulfilled).catch(onRejected);
```

is *different* from

```
aPromise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

The first one hooks up a fulfillment handler to `aPromise`, and then hooks up a rejection handler to the promise `then` returns (which means the rejection handler will be called if `aPromise` rejects **or** if the fulfillment handler throws an error or returns a promise that rejects). In contrast, the second one only hooks up handlers on `aPromise`, so errors/rejections from the fulfillment handler do not trigger the rejection handler.

---

¹ In fact, `.catch(fn)` is just a wrapper for `.then(undefined, fn)`. :-) [spec link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise.prototype.catch)

Answer (score -2):

if the function pass to `then` returns a promise,

```js
promise
    .then(
        (async (response)=>{
            ...
        }).catch((errorFromThen) => {})
    ).catch((errorFromPromise) => {})
```

or just simply

```js
promise
    .then(
        (response)=>{
            try {
                ...
            } catch (errorFromThen) {
                ...
            }
        }
    ).catch((errorFromPromise) => {})
```